# how to recyle the bitmap which runs multi-thread

Tags: android, multithreading, bitmap

the activity displays the bitmap which load from the internet ,when I slip the ImageView,another bitmap will occur.I set the bitmap to ImageView and after recycle it, sometimes,the error has occurs.
the code:

```
mImageView.setImageBitmap(loadedBitmap);
if(loadedBitmap!=null && !loadedBitmap.isRecycled()){
   loadedBitmap.recycle();
   loadedBitmap=null;
}
```

It runs multi-thread,I can not put the operation of Bitmpa recycle ahead of setImageBitmap.
how should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well basically you cannot recycle a bitmap that you're currently using in your ImageView.
If you want to swap the bitmap in your ImageView then I would do it like this:

I would keep a reference to the Bitmap (in for example mLoadedBitmap), and when you download another one you do something like this:

```
final Bitmap oldBitmap = mLoadedBitmap;
mLoadedBitmap = downloadedBitmap;
mImageView.setImageBitmap(mLoadedBitmap);
if(oldBitmap!=null && !oldBitmap.isRecycled()){
    oldBitmap.recycle();
}
```

Comment: If it helped with your issue, pls make sure to accept the answer.

Comment: how should I accept it? I'm a new learner.when I vote for your answer, it displays require 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a multi-threaded application but do all the UI updates from the main thread.